# How do I obtain a Structure.ByReference from a Structure using JNA?

Tags: java, c, jruby, jna

I do have a object of Structure in my java code. But the Jar generated using JNAerator expects Structure.ByReference as a data type. Is there any method in jna or code snippet to convert Structure object into Structure.ByReference object?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you don't need to explicitly specify `Structure.ByReference` when passing parameters.  If it's a parameter, you can drop the `.ByReference` from the signature and it'll work just fine.

If it's a field within a structure, then JNA interprets `Structure` as by value, in which case you *would* need to provide the `.ByReference` explicitly.

This is one way to do it.

```
class MyStructure extends Structure {
    class ByReference extends MyStructure implements Structure.ByReference {
        public ByReference() { }
        public Byreference(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
    }
    public MyStructure() { }
    public MyStructure(Pointer p) { super(p); read(); }
}

MyStructure s;
// ...
MyStructure.ByReference ref = new MyStructure.ByReference(s.getPointer());
```

Comment: Yes, it's the field within a structure and I do have an object of JNA Structure. So now I need to convert it into Structure.ByReference so that it can be assignable to structure field.

Comment: JNA will automatically initialize the field when it's reading the containing structure from native memory.  In order to initialize it yourself, you simply need to create an instance of `MyStructure.ByReference` and initialize it, or initialize it from an existing structure or memory block using the pattern above.